# Galleria won't load completely; doesn't show starting image

Tags: phonegap-build, galleria

I am trying to use Galleria from a Phonegap project. Testing on ios 10.
I've initialized Galleria with 2 images, using the datasource option. It doesn't show any starting image, and the counter shows -/2. The thumbnails are visible, and whenever I click a thumbnail image or swipe, the image shows correctly, and the counter is updated (for example it shows 1/2).

```
var data = [
        { image: "http://www.<something>" },
        { image: "http://<somethingelse" }
    ];
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');

    var gall = Galleria.run('.galleria',  {
        dataSource: data,
        showImagenav: false
    });
```

The ready event wouldn't fire, and as a result gall is undefined after the run call.

Why wouldn't Galleria run/load completely?

Thanks